# BJT Amplifier Circuit Analysis Feedback

Tags: circuit-analysis, bjt, small-signal

I've been reading up on small signal analysis to try and better understand audio amplifier circuit design (end goal a discrete BJT guitar amplifier). I'm attempting to apply the knowledge I've picked up (from Microelectronic circuits - Sedra/Smith) to the following amplifier schematic:

[image]

Would anyone be able to offer some guidance on whether or not I'm doing the correct analysis?

**Assumptions:**
$$\beta = 100$$
$$V_{A} = 100$$
$$V_{be} = 0.7$$

**So:**
$$(1) = 7mA$$
$$(2) \approx 4.6mA$$

**Signal Input Impedance (R IN1):**
$$r_{\pi} = \frac{\beta \cdot V_{T}}{I_{C}}$$
$$r_{\pi} = \frac{100 \cdot 25mV}{2.3mA} \approx 1087 \Omega$$
$$R_{IN1} = R9 || r_{\pi}$$
$$R_{IN1} = 100k \Omega || 1087 \Omega$$
$$R_{IN1} \approx 1075 \Omega$$

**Diff Pair Signal Output Impedance (R OUT1):**
$$r_{o} = \frac{V_{A}}{I_{C}}$$
$$r_{o} = \frac{100V}{2.6mA}$$
$$r_{o} \approx 38462 \Omega$$
$$R_{OUT1} = r_{o}$$

**Gain (Avo):**
$$A_{vo} = -g_{m} \cdot r_{o}$$
$$A_{vo} = - \frac{I_{C}}{V_{T}} \cdot \frac{V_{A}}{I_{C}} = \frac{V_{A}}{V_{T}}$$
$$A_{vo} = -\frac{100V}{25mA}$$
$$A_{vo} = 4,000 V/V$$

Many Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you plug the circuit into a simulator and find out yourself? You'll get a much more accurate picture than trying to resolve things with overly-simple maths and random comments from anyone not using a sim.

Comment: Cdevelop, perhaps redraw the schematic (it's not bad, but the sections can be better isolated.) Then identify each section and add a description for them -- tell us what they do and why they are there. At that point, ask one (maybe two) questions that are more important to you about a section, where the nicely organized and section-isolated schematic provides the context for the question on a section. For example, it takes a moment to see what the VBE-multiplier separates and it doesn't deal with the Early Effect. It has a pot, but why between base and emitter and not base and collector?

Comment: Thanks @jonk I'll do just that - appreciate the guidance again!